# In Aspnet WebApI 4.6 HttpModule, wrong Http statuscode is shown for 404 erros

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

In aspnet web API 4.6, I am getting 200 status code when 404 was expected. Following is the module that can reproduce this.

```
internal class HttpRequestLoggerModule : IHttpModule
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes the module
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context">application initializing the module</param>
        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.EndRequest += OnEndRequest;
        }

        private static void OnEndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var application = (HttpApplication)sender;

            // Why this is 200 for 404 requests where route was incorrect and no handler was found.
            var statusCode = application.Context.Response.StatusCode;
        }
    }
```

This is hosted in IIS and seems like 404 is returned by IIS and http module gets executed after the fact. Is there any way to capture correct status in the http module?

Comment: That can happen with a redirect. The not found (404) can get handled and redirected (302) to a error page which returns 200 when loaded.

Comment: This is aspnet webapi and there is no error page registration. IIS is doing something out of the box and i don't see any way to intercept the correct status being returned from an HttpModule.